Why is the shared-memory set() updated multiple times instead of once
The following code will build an empty shared memory set() for multiple process to access, populate individually, and then fuse to obtain one bigger set used by other functions.
class CustomManager(BaseManager):
    # nothing
    pass
CustomManager.register('shared_set', set)
manager = CustomManager()
manager.start()
shared_kmer_set = manager.shared_set()

def classify_reads(fastq_file, bloom_filter, kmer_size, n_consecutive_matches, output, shared_anchor_kmer_set):
    kmer_set = set()
    # populates the kmer_set
    print(len(kmer_set))
    shared_anchor_kmer_set.update(anchor_kmer_set)


processes = [Process(target=classify_reads, args=(i, present_kmers_bf, shared_k_size.value, shared_n_consec_matches.value, shared_output.value, shared_kmer_set)) for i in args["input"]]
    for i in range(0, len(processes), args["threads"]):
        for process in processes[i:i + args["threads"]]:
            process.start()
    for process in processes:
         process.join()
    for process in processes:
        process.terminate()

print(len(str(shared_kmer_set)))

def classify_reads_using_anchor_kmers(shared_kmer_set, file):
    copy_set = str(shared_kmer_set)
    for line in file:
       if line in copy_set:
            print(line)

 processes = [Process(target=classify_reads_using_anchor_kmers, args=(i, shared_kmer_set, shared_k_size.value, shared_anchor_proportion_cutoff.value, shared_output.value)) for i in args["input"]]
    for i in range(0, len(processes), args["threads"]):
        for process in processes[i:i + args["threads"]]:
            process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    for process in processes:
        process.terminate()



I noticed the next functions using the set were very slow and after printing variables as shown in the code, the values are, with only one file and thus one process:
419056
14666960

Which is a change of 350 fold. I have trouble understanding how this happens. It would explain why the next lines of the program take so much time checking if an element is in the set.

shared_kmer_set.do_stuff() Will pickle the arguments, send them to another process, unpickle them, then run the function, then pickle the result, then send it back, then unpickle the result. It should be slow, you shouldn't be using it that frequently.

@AhmedAEK The shared kmer_set is only updated once per process. Were it is slow is when I check if elements are in there. Per your comment it should not be this slow at this stage, but eventually when updating the set, right ?

Any action on it is slow, the if in check is basically set.__contains__(), the manager has a single GIL, when one process is updating the set the others will be blocked, your code is slower than using a single process.

@AhmedAEK With the new code added (next function which copies a str() of the shared set, all th updates on the shared set are done before using it to check elements. It is still very slow, even with the copy of a representation of the shared set.
